# ClickOnce issue with Corporate IT client

Tags: wpf, clickonce

So I am having some difficulty with our WPF ClickOnce deployment. I knew that we would run into issues when our clients from coporations with complex IT policies started installing. Up to this point, I have not had an issue. The application itself has a prerequisite of .NET 4.5 – which I know requires administrator privileges. Here is the error that the client is sending to me:

```
“C:\documents and settings\gdevlin\local settings\Temporary Internet Files\content.ie5\9wkrp310\setup[1].exe

Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item.”
```

Seems pretty obvious to me. They have of course consulted their IT dept and they confirm that there should be no problems and that they have sufficient permissions. They did note that the setup.exe file is empty – that file should be around 430 kb.

Comment: this is completely unrelated, but `C:\documents and settings\ ` sounds like Windows XP. .Net 4.5 is not supported on Windows XP.

Comment: yeah sorry,.... That was the original message. I know that they can't use 4.5 with XP. They said they got the same message with Windows 7 machine.